# Finding empty space in time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to find the available time slots where a period of time is not taken.
For example, given the following table:

```
Table 1

UserID         Start              End   

1        2014-06-02 09:00   2014-06-02 14:00
2        2014-06-02 19:00   2014-06-02 21:00
3        2014-06-02 20:00   2014-06-02 22:00
4        2014-06-03 03:00   2014-06-03 08:00
5        2014-06-03 13:00   2014-06-03 15:00
6        2014-06-03 20:00   2014-06-03 23:00
7        2014-06-03 23:00   2014-06-04 05:00
8        2014-06-04 09:00   2014-06-04 13:00


Expected result:

Start                           End

2014-06-02 00:00        2014-06-02 09:00
2014-06-02 14:00        2014-06-02 19:00
2014-06-02 22:00        2014-06-03 00:00
2014-06-02 00:00        2014-06-03 03:00
2014-06-03 08:00        2014-06-03 13:00
2014-06-03 15:00        2014-06-03 20:00
2014-06-04 05:00        2014-06-04 09:00
2014-06-04 13:00        2014-06-05 00:00
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not very familiar with sql but I need this for a program I'm building, so any hint or help will be appriciated

Comment: We aren't going to write all your code for you. Try something first, and when you have a specific problem *then* come back and ask.

Comment: i'm not looking for code necessarily. any hint or thought process would be nice though since I'm kind of stuck

Comment: So try something and see what you get.  Then show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query consists of two queries with UNION. First one: we give all END dates and select the next (MIN) start date. Your data contains overlapped intervals so there is EXISTS condition to exclude these END dates. The second query is to get the first line - from the start of a day to the first START time.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT End as Start,
       COALESCE((SELECT MIN(Start) FROM T WHERE Start>T1.End),
              DATE_ADD(DATE((SELECT MAX(END) FROM T)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
         ) as End

FROM T as T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T 
                           WHERE T1.End 
                                 between Start and End
                                 and UserID<>T1.UserID )

UNION ALL 
SELECT DATE(MIN(START)) as Start,
       MIN(START) as End
FROM T 
) as T2
ORDER BY Start
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98475/18)</kbd>